# Weird behaviour of Spring's InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException, gets called twice inside same catch block

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having below service method where `company` data is created. `Company` have `1:1` relation with `CompanyType` which has fixed set of values and more values cannnot be inserted. It's an read only table. So, for below method, I am passing the wrong(which doesn't exist in DB) value to the `company`. Ofcourse `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` will be thrown by Spring. But I noticed that the catch block is being called twice. Isn't it a weird behaviour?

```
public Company create(Company company) {
        Company createdCompany = null;
        try {
            company.setUser(userDao.findByEmail("abc@gmail.com")
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new AccessDeniedException("You are not authenticated for this operation")));
            createdCompany = companyDao.save(company);
        } catch (InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException ex) {
            // will be thrown if the company-type provided doesn't exist.
//          LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("*********************************************************");
            throw new BadRequestException("Selected company type/category doesn't exist");
        }
        return createdCompany;

    }
```

logs

```
2019-06-06 03:03:27 ERROR c.o.s.i.CompanyServiceImpl - *********************************************************
2019-06-06 03:03:27 ERROR c.o.s.i.CompanyServiceImpl - *********************************************************
```

Comment: 1. The log message is not coming from the code you show. It is an ERROR message, but you are logging INFO.

2. The most likely reason for running into a catch block twice is that the method gets called twice. Set a break point at the first line of the method or add logging.
It might also be helpful to log the full exception to see where the call is coming from

Comment: @JensSchauder Sorry, I forget to update the method here. On my system it's `error()` only. Before asking it here, I tried setting debugger points but eclipse is giving some error for line numbers and so I am unable to debug the application flow.

Comment: just put statements in creating a new exception and printing the stacktrace to the console. Clunky but works.

Comment: so I printed stack trace `ex.printStackTrace()` and also printed the error in logfile. Strange, the stack trace on the console is only one time but the log file contain two duplicate logs. Is this you wanted to check with this?

Comment: This sounds like like you have two appenders configured for logging. Check your logging configuration.

Comment: yup. That was the issue. I was having a root logger pointing to the same file. That extra logging was from root logger. Thanks a ton, @JensSchauder. And your solution to debug maybe was clunky but it was effective 